# persistor.getState is not s function -- redux-persist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-persist

I am trying to persist my immutable states in localStorage. Below is my reducer index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import posts from './PostReducer';
import polls from './PollReducer';
import categories from './CategoryReducer';
import activeThreads from './ActiveThreadReducer';

export default combineReducers({
    posts,
    polls,
    categories,
    activeThreads
})
```

In my persistStore.js, i have something like below.

```
import immutableTransform from 'redux-persist-transform-immutable'

import { persistStore, autoRehydrate } from 'redux-persist-immutable';
import { persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';

import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';



const config = {
    key: 'root',
    storage,
};


const loggerMiddleware = createLogger();


const finalCreateStore =
    composeWithDevTools(
        applyMiddleware(
            thunkMiddleware,
            loggerMiddleware,
        ),
        autoRehydrate()
    );

const reducer = persistReducer(config, reducers)


export const store = createStore(reducer, undefined, finalCreateStore);
export const persistor = persistStore(store, { transforms: [immutableTransform({})] }, () => {
    console.log('rehydration complete', store.getState());

    return store;
});
```

and in my main APP,

```
return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate
          loading={<Loading />}
          onBeforeLift={this.onBeforeLift}
          persistor={persistor}>
          <Router history={browserHistory}
            createElement={this.createElementWithActions}>
            <Route path="/" component={Main}>
              ...
          </Router>
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    );
```

My app is returning the error below.

> Uncaught TypeError: persistor.getState is not a function
>       at PersistGate._this.handlePersistorState (react.js:41)
>       at PersistGate.componentDidMount (react.js:55)
>       at ReactCompositeComponent.js:262
>       at measureLifeCyclePerf (ReactCompositeComponent.js:73)
>       at ReactCompositeComponent.js:261
>       at CallbackQueue.notifyAll (CallbackQueue.js:74)
>       at ReactReconcileTransaction.close (ReactReconcileTransaction.js:78)
>       at ReactReconcileTransaction.closeAll (Transaction.js:207)
>       at ReactReconcileTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:154)
>       at batchedMountComponentIntoNode (ReactMount.js:124)

I read the documentation on redux-persist here  and [Here](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist). Please what am i doing wrong and what does the error implies ?Anyhelp would be appreciated

Comment: do you see your log `console.log('rehydration complete', store.getState());` ?

Comment: @Freez yes. I do see it . But the error happens before that. The error is the first console. Then the `console.log('rehydration complete', store.getState());`